# Why does my notification is exists method always return null?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I've searched many times on stackoverflow.
I've found isexists method if a notification exists or not. But when I try it,it always return null. Where is my mistake?

I run this code in my service class and in my service class I create notification like this:

```
NotificationBck_l a; 
a= new NotificationBck_l(context);
a.createNotification();
```

my method is here(it is in my service class too):

```
   private boolean isNotificationVisible_l() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationBck.class);
        PendingIntent test = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NOT_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        return test != null;
    }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660451

Comment: thanks for answer , as i said I ve searched many times and I ve seen that link and try it , no success :(

Comment: why you are returning test, return test != null;

Comment: ok ı edit my question and still no success

Comment: **isNotificationVisible_l()** return always false

Comment: I edit my question with more detail

Comment: What is `NotificationBck_l` and what does the method `createNotification()` do?

Comment: it is a class that create notification on android client

Comment: Try using builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true); If you want to send single notification.